# delete cookie when browser closed

Tags: javascript

i need to delete cookie when browser is closed and already put on window.onbeforeunload along with other as following:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        location.replace("admin.jsp?action=logout");
        deleteCookie('Times');
 }
```

with setCookie as following:

```
 function setCookie(name,value,days) {
         var expires;
         if (days) {
                  var date = new Date();
                  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                  expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
         }
         else {
                  expires = "";
              }
                  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
     }
```

when it comes to deleteCookie, it contains as below:

```
    setCookie(name,value,-1);
```

The problem is whenever i restart browser, it always comes to window.onbeforeunload so that deleteCookie fired. I actually need this to reset my countdown timer whenever user logs in since the cookie never deleted if the counter doesn't end and user sometimes closes window/tab before it ends. So, my idea is either reset the counter when user logs in or simply delete cookie when user logs out. I still can't figure out how to code this, however. Can anyone help me out? Code snippet will be appreciated, though. CMIIW

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question but maybe your want a session instead, take a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608764/purpose-of-php-sessions-and-cookies-and-their-differences.

Comment: @PeterJ: I'm currently using JSP or JSTL, how can i implement this via session since i need this not to dect first page but to detect after login which redirected to another page. I already attempted to use session.isNew() but it only worked for index.jsp. CMIIW

Comment: I don't know how you're initializing the cookie, but if you don't provide an expiration for it, it will expire when you close the browser. Not sure if that helps...

Comment: @Ian: I initialize the cookie by using setCookie('Times,value, 1) which 1 refers to 1 day. I made it that way since in my codes, when the counter ends, deleteCookie will be fired. CMIIW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not specifying Expires value on the cookie will cause the cookie to be removed when the browser session ends i.e. when user closes the browser. Like:

```
Set-Cookie: made_write_conn=1295214458; Path=/; Domain=.foo.com
```

The `made_write_conn` cookie made_write_conn does not have an expiration date, making it a session cookie. It will be deleted after the user closes his/her browser.
Try doing:

```
setCookie('Times',value, '');
```

Comment: please see my setCookie code on edited question above. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The only "problem" with this is that if this is a session cookie, the session will still be alive. There's no way for a cookie to report to the server when it's been expired, in order for the server to clean up anything. If it's not a session, then this is the cleanest way

Comment: @Ian: So, what's the solution?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono Did you completely close the browser? It won't work if you just close your tab but keep other tabs open.

Comment: @Ian: I closed only the tab.

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono you need to close the browser itself, not its tabs, try closing the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the page's location when the browser is being closed.

On the server you should be using [session end events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118968/sessiontimeout-web-xml-vs-session-maxinactiveinterval) to clean up the account.

Comment: @espascerallo: I'm not really sure with this but it does go to logout page which indicated by removing the user from database. CMIIW

Comment: Are you doing it on localhost or out on the wild web?