# Setting Session cookies to expire in keen.io

Tags: javascript, keen-io

Having some issues with setting a cookie to expire on window close

Keen provide some good utilities such as `Keen.utils.cookie('sessioncookie')`

However I'm still struggling. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, will update the question to reflect. I have set the cookie - more about destroying it on window close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete cookie when browser closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872305/delete-cookie-when-browser-closed)

Answer (score 1):

The [Keen IO](https://keen.io/) keen-js library and keen-tracking JavaScript library uses [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) under the hood. js-cookie is a simple, lightweight JavaScript API for handling browser cookies.

The js-cookie library will remove cookies by default when the browser is closed, unless an expiration value is set. This shows where to set that here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/README.md#expires